# How to dynamically create centered rows of three images?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to dynamically create centered rows of three images. For example, if I am loading in three images, I would have one row. If four images, load two rows, and if ten images, then four rows. My images are of fixed size and so is the container div that surround them.

My initial approach was to apply float: left to all, which worked to some extent. I had rows of three images, and when I made my browser skinnier, some images moved to the next row, which is what I wanted. However, the images were not centered, which I also need.

If anyone knows how to do this using javascript and css, that would be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, but I think the simplest way would be to make the images display inline-block and remove all of their margins and paddings. You'll also need to get rid of the whitespace between the images by using font-size 0.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .rowimg {
                display:inline-block;
                /* by default, there should be no padding/margin, but remove them just in case*/
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                vertical-align:middle; /* important if the images are different sizes*/
            }
            #imgcontainer {
                font-size:0; /* gets rid of the spaces in between images */
                text-align:center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="imgcontainer">
            <img src="..." class="rowimg">
            <img src="..." class="rowimg">
            <img src="..." class="rowimg">
            <img src="..." class="rowimg">
            <img src="..." class="rowimg">
            <img src="..." class="rowimg">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```